# how can i make ajax-waiting until i fetch some information from database?

Tags: javascript, ajax

how can i make ajax-waiting until i fetch some information form database?

for example

```
 function cat()
      {
        my_info = "<?php ..fetching database information .. ?>";
        table = document.getElementById('table_2');
          table.innerHTML=my_info;
      }
```

what should i do to view ajax-loading `gif` until i complete get the info to display to the end-user?

Comment: It's going to be impossible in the way you show. How long does this fetching take? What kind of data are you fetching? You may need to look into Ajax to fetch the data

Comment: Also, it seems to me that you're not using ajax at all - you're simply generating the HTML via PHP with the value for the `my_info` var already set. Keep in mind that PHP is server-side and will have already run *before* the page is rendered in the browser which is when the JavaScript will have a chance to execute.

Answer (score 0):

you can place code to view loading image just after you make the ajax request(send() method if you are using plain javasacript).

```
 request.open("GET", url, true);
 request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
 request.send(null);
 // write code to show your image here
```

Then hide that image in the callback function `updatePage()`

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has to give you a jQuery alternative, so here I am: set up the ajax calls to show an image before sending the ajax call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loadingImage').show()
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loadingImage').hide()
  }
});
```

and then set the ajax call as

```
$.get(url, function (response) {$("#myTable").html(response);});
```